# Footer not staying at bottom

Tags: html, css, web, footer

Hi I know there are many questions about the same thing and i have tried those answers and none of them have worked.
So I have gone and used min-height:1000px; on the mainbody of my website so make all the pages the same size, but after doing this is has messed up my footer big time, the footer is now in the middle of the page and no longer goes the full width of the page, it is just in the left hand side of the page,

HTML

```
<footer>
&copy; Digital Canvas Web Designs est 2012
</footer>
</div> <!--wrapper-->
```

and CSS

```
footer {
position:absolute;
width:auto;
bottom:0;
height:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
border-top-color: #990012;
border-top-width:2px;
border-top-style:solid;
text-align:center;
font-family:georgia, serif;
font-style:italic;
font-size:0.75em;
}
```

I want the border to go all the way across the bottom of the page.
Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Have you tried to use *position: relative* instead of *absolute*. See http://jsfiddle.net/dq2zse2t/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for : http://www.emmanuelbeziat.com/blog/un-site-qui-prend-toute-la-hauteur-disponible/ (There's a codepen at the end of the article if you wish)

If you need translation, i'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Try define the width to be 100%

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    border-top-color: #990012;
    border-top-width:2px;
    border-top-style:solid;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:georgia, serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:0.75em;
}
```

Comment: It's generally better to use left:0; and right:0;. width:100%; is generally a bad idea, and most of time you can simply avoid it (except on form fields and tables).

http://codepen.io/Manumanu/pen/ryhaC
http://blog.goetter.fr/articles/width-100-tu-es-le-mal/ (fr)

Answer (score 0):

Edit.
Try position:relative to #wrapper and position:absolute; bottom:0; to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Listed are a couple of tricks to resolve your footer issues:
https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

The one that worked best for me was:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="main-container">

      content

  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#main-container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing position to relative.

```
.wrapper{
position :absolute;
}

footer {
position:relative;
}
```